# loop between a nested object array and another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have two arrays, one it normal array and other is object array.
 All I want here is show me how to make a loop between both of them to get "**Jhon**" is **good** and sum of (midterm+finalterm)
In a :
the first no is no of school, the second is class>> i will use .split("|") to make them in an array 
In b: object array

> I don't want the whole code, just the loop and if condition

the function will compare 1|1 in a with school_no and class_no to match

but I want if condition to color the name of the student based on evaluation like red for bad and blue for good.

here the arrays

```js
a=["1|1|Jhon","1|2|Akram","1|3|Mali"]
    //first no for school no
    //second no for class no.
    b= [{
        "result": [
          {
            "midterm": 25,
            "evaluation": "good",
            "finalterm": 24
          }
        ],
        "school  _no": 1,
        "class_no": 1
      },
      {
        "result": [
          {
            "midterm": 55,
            "evaluation": "verygood",
            "finalterm": 60
          }
        ],
        "school_no": 1,
        "class_no": 2
      },
    {
        "result": [
          {
            "midterm": 11,
            "evaluation": "bad",
            "finalterm": 12
          }
        ],
        "school_no": 1,
        "class_no": 3
      }
    
    ];
    console.log(a);
    console.log(b);
```

this is not a homework yet it's a small example of something bigger I'm working on.

Comment: `a=[1|1|"Jhon",1|2|"Akram",1|3|"Mali"]` should be `a=["1|1|Jhon","1|2|Akram","1|3|Mali"]`, right?

Comment: @user3297291 I would assume so otherwise the current "a" will output [1,3,3] in console.

Comment: yes, i made mistake. sorry

Comment: Are the students in array `a` always matched to the results in `b` by index? Or do you need to explicitly check every result for every student based on the two properties?

Comment: @user3297291 yes it match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply You have to iterate the data of `a`(student) and find the school no and class no in `b`(results):

```js
a=["1|1|Jhon","1|2|Akram","1|3|Mali"]
//first no for school no
//second no for class no.
b= [{
    "result": [
      {
        "midterm": 25,
        "evaluation": "good",
        "finalterm": 24
      }
    ],
    "school_no": 1,
    "class_no": 1
  },
  {
    "result": [
      {
        "midterm": 55,
        "evaluation": "verygood",
        "finalterm": 60
      }
    ],
    "school_no": 1,
    "class_no": 2
  },
{
    "result": [
      {
        "midterm": 11,
        "evaluation": "bad",
        "finalterm": 12
      }
    ],
    "school_no": 1,
    "class_no": 3
  }

];
var result=[]
a.forEach(function(element) {
  var data= element.split("|");
 
  var found = b.find(function(element) {
  return element.school_no == data[0] && element.class_no== data[1];
});
 result.push(data[2]+" is "+found.result[0].evaluation+" and sum of (midterm+finalterm) is :"+(found.result[0].midterm+found.result[0].finalterm));
 document.getElementById(data[2]).className = found.result[0].evaluation;

});
console.log(result);
```

```css
.good {
    color: blue;
}

.bad {
    color: red;
}

.verygood {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="Jhon">Jhon</div>
<div id="Akram">Akram</div>
<div id="Mali">Mali</div>
```

Comment: Thank you first of all. but is there any way of coloring without using div.

Answer (score 0):

What I understood is you want to generate new array which contains list of object which contains string and your color based on evaluation.

```js
var a=["1|1|Jhon","1|2|Akram","1|3|Mali"]
//first no for school no
//second no for class no.
var b= [{
"result": [
  {
    "midterm": 25,
    "evaluation": "good",
    "finalterm": 24
  }
],
"school_no": 1,
"class_no": 1
  },
  {
"result": [
  {
    "midterm": 55,
    "evaluation": "verygood",
    "finalterm": 60
  }
],
"school_no": 1,
"class_no": 2
  },
{
"result": [
  {
    "midterm": 11,
    "evaluation": "bad",
    "finalterm": 12
  }
],
"school_no": 1,
"class_no": 3
  }
];


var resultArrNew = a.reduce(function(ac, val) {
    var valArra = val.split("|");
var matched = b.filter(function(obj) {
    return obj.school_no == valArra[0] && obj.class_no == valArra[1];
});
var text = valArra[2] + " is " + matched[0].result[0].evaluation + " and sum is " + (matched[0].result[0].midterm+matched[0].result[0].finalterm);
var color = matched[0].result[0].evaluation === 'good' ? 'blue' : 'red';

ac.push({text: text, color: color});
return ac;
}, []);
console.log(resultArrNew);
```

Answer (score 0):

If they are in the same order, and the `result[0]` is always the one matching the student, you can do an ordinary loop and access by index:

```js
const students = [ "1|1|Jhon",  "1|2|Akram","1|3|Mali" ];
const results = [{result:[{midterm:25,evaluation:"good",finalterm:24}],school_no:1,class_no:1},{result:[{midterm:55,evaluation:"verygood",finalterm:60}],school_no:1,class_no:2},{result:[{midterm:11,evaluation:"bad",finalterm:12}],school_no:1,class_no:3}];


for (let i = 0; i < students.length; i += 1) {
  const student = students[i];
  const result = results[i];
  
  console.log({
    name: parseStudentName(student),
    result: getResultColor(result),
  });
}

function parseStudentName(studentString) {
  return studentString.split("|")[2]
};

function getResultColor(result) {
  switch(result.result[0].evaluation) {
    case "verygood":
    case "good":
      return "blue";
    case "bad":
      return "red";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You got an error on the 2nd array => `school  _no`

I simply iterate throught `a` array. Each student item i searched for a node in `b` array, returning the `node.result` array.

```js
a=["1|1|Jhon","1|2|Akram","1|3|Mali"]
//first no for school no
//second no for class no.
b= [{
    "result": [
      {
        "midterm": 25,
        "evaluation": "good",
        "finalterm": 24
      }
    ],
    "school_no": 1,
    "class_no": 1
  },
  {
    "result": [
      {
        "midterm": 55,
        "evaluation": "verygood",
        "finalterm": 60
      }
    ],
    "school_no": 1,
    "class_no": 2
  },
{
    "result": [
      {
        "midterm": 11,
        "evaluation": "bad",
        "finalterm": 12
      }
    ],
    "school_no": 1,
    "class_no": 3
  }
];

for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    var parts = a[i].split('|');
    try {
        var node = getStudentNode(parseInt(parts[0]), parseInt(parts[1]));
        console.log(node);
    }
    catch(ex){
        console.log(ex);
    }
}

function getStudentNode(sc, cl) {
    for(var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        var node = b[i];
        if(node.school_no !== sc || node.class_no !== cl) continue;
        return node.result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it with a more functional approach

```js
const a =["1|1|Jhon", "1|2|Akram", "1|3|Mali"]

const b = [{
    "result": [
      {
        "midterm": 25,
        "evaluation": "good",
        "finalterm": 24
      }
    ],
    "school  _no": 1,
    "class_no": 1
  },
  {
    "result": [
      {
        "midterm": 55,
        "evaluation": "verygood",
        "finalterm": 60
      }
    ],
    "school_no": 1,
    "class_no": 2
  },
{
    "result": [
      {
        "midterm": 11,
        "evaluation": "bad",
        "finalterm": 12
      }
    ],
    "school_no": 1,
    "class_no": 3
  }
];

// import some functional helpers
const { map, propPathOr, compose } = crocks

const getStudent = record => {
  const [school_no, class_no, student_name] = record.split('|')
  return { school_no, class_no, student_name }
}

const getStudents = map(getStudent)

const getEvaluation = propPathOr('', ['result', 0, 'evaluation'])

const getEvaluations = map(getEvaluation)

// assuming your lists are sorted
const zip = (xs, ys) => xs.map((x, i) => [x, ys[i]])

const combineStudentAndEvaluation = ([student, evaluation]) =>
  ({ ...student, evaluation })

const stringify = ({student_name, evaluation}) =>
  `${student_name}: ${evaluation}`

const studentEvaluationToString = compose(stringify, combineStudentAndEvaluation)

const merged = zip(getStudents(a), getEvaluations(b))
  .map(studentEvaluationToString)
    
console.log(merged)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/crocks/dist/crocks.min.js"></script>
```